# How do I return the sum of the three largest elements in an array?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return sum of 3 largest numbers in an array like this:

```
fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    arr.sort();
    arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]
}
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*arr` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference

fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
                   ------ help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut [i32]`

    arr.sort();
       ^^^ `arr` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

I shouldn't change `arr: &[i32]` to `arr: &mut [i32]` because of some restrictions. So what can I do about it?

P.S: I tried to clone `arr` to a mutable variable but got other errors:

```
fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let a: &mut [i32] = *arr.clone();
    a.sort();
    a[0]+a[1]+a[2]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, you can't have a variable that has both reference and mutable reference in the same scope.

You have several choices :

- You could simply do a loop on the slice to get the values you want. Something like this (there's probably a more elegant way with iterators)

```rust
    fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut maxes = [0, 0, 0];
    for &el in arr {
        if el > maxes[0] && el < maxes[1] {
            maxes[0] = el;
        } else if el > maxes[1] && el < maxes[2] {
            if maxes[1] > maxes[0] {
                maxes[0] = maxes[1];
            }
            maxes[1] = el;
        } else if el > maxes[2] {
            if maxes[2] > maxes[1] {
                maxes[1] = maxes[2];
            }
            maxes[2] = el;
        }
    }

    maxes[0] + maxes[1] + maxes[2]
    }
```

- You can create a new `Vec` from the slice, and then do all the operations on it (which requires allocation, but should be fine for small `Vec`s).

```rust
    fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
        let mut arr = Vec::from(arr);
        arr.sort();
        arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]
    }
```

I would also like to point that `sort` sorts from smallest to biggest, so the index `0, 1, 2, ...` would be the smallest values in the array, which I don't think is what you want to do!

Comment: Your first version require heap allocation too. It would be better to use `let mut maxes = [0,0,0];` instead of `vec!`.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Good point! I'll upadte my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a BinaryHeap to store the three largest values so far and replace the smallest value while looping through the array:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();
    heap.push(-arr[0]);
    heap.push(-arr[1]);
    heap.push(-arr[2]);
    
    for e in arr[3..].iter() {
        if -e < *heap.peek().unwrap() {
            heap.pop();
            heap.push(-e);
        } 
    }
    -heap.drain().sum::<i32>()
}
```

Or if you prefer the sort option, you can convert the slice to a vector:

```
fn max_tri_sum(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut arr1 = arr.to_vec();
    arr1.sort_by(|a, b| b.cmp(a));
    arr1[0] + arr1[1] + arr1[2]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c349fcbbcc4492304acf4adcccbbf244)